# R / using vectorization to check if columns in exist in a df

Tags: r, vectorization, sapply

I have defined the following function to check if a data frame contains several columns and to include them if not.

```
CheckFullCohorts <- function(df) {
  # Checks if year/cohort df contains all necessary columns 
  # Args:
  #  df: year/cohort df

  # Return:
  #  df: df, corrected if necessary 

  foo <- function(mydf, mystring) {
    if(!(mystring %in% names(mydf))) {
      mydf[mystring] <- 0
    }
    mydf
  }

  df <- foo(df, "age.16.20")
  df <- foo(df, "age.21.24")
  df <- foo(df, "age.25.49")
  df <- foo(df, "age.50.57")
  df <- foo(df, "age.58.65")
  df <- foo(df, "age.66.70")

  df
}
```

I would use this function as follows:

```
test <- data.frame(age.16.20 = rep("x", 5), lorem = rep("y", 5))

test <- CheckFullCohorts(test)
```

**Problem:** How can I make the hardcoded part of the function (`df <- foo(...`) more flexible by using a vector of column names to check?

I've tried:

```
CheckFullCohorts <- function(df, col.list) {
  # Checks if year/cohort df contains all necessary columns 
  # Args:
  #  df: year/cohort df
  #  col.list: named list of columns

  # Return:
  #  df: df, corrected if necessary 

  foo <- function(mydf, mystring) {
    if(!(mystring %in% names(mydf))) {
      mydf[mystring] <- 0
    }
    mydf
  }

  df <- sapply(df, foo, mystring = col.list) 

  df
}
```

...but I get a wrong result:

```
test <- data.frame(age.16.20 = rep("x", 5), lorem = rep("y", 5))
test <- CheckFullCohorts(test, c("age.16.20", "age.20.25"))

Warning messages:
1: In if (!(mystring %in% names(mydf))) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, mystring, value = 0) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
3: In if (!(mystring %in% names(mydf))) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
4: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, mystring, value = 0) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
> test
          age.16.20 lorem
          "x"       "y"  
          "x"       "y"  
          "x"       "y"  
          "x"       "y"  
          "x"       "y"  
age.16.20 NA        NA   
age.20.25 NA        NA
```

Comment: What about passing a vector of strings `S` to `CheckFullCohort`, then replace the lines in question with `for(s in S){df <- foo(df, s)}`?

Comment: Sure, that would work. Does that mean this one of the cases where loops are more efficient than a vectorized solution? And if it is, I'd still love to know what I'm doing wrong with my `sapply`.

Comment: Whether loops are efficient or not depends on whether the data frame is copied at each interaction, and I don't know if it will be the case here. But the discussion about loops not being efficient is often overblown: is this step the bottleneck in your code? If not, it's not where you should spend energy optimizing. As for `sapply`, good question -- I tend to use `plyr` for these things, the interface makes more sense to me. PS, @Roland's answer below works too and do not require a function!

Comment: The problem with your `sapply` attempt is that you should loop over `col.list` instead of over `df`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can vectorize this easily:

```
test <- data.frame(age.16.20 = rep("x", 5), lorem = rep("y", 5))
musthaves <- c("age.16.20", "age.21.24", "age.25.49",
               "age.50.57", "age.58.65", "age.66.70")

test[musthaves[!(musthaves %in% names(test))]] <- 0
#  age.16.20 lorem age.21.24 age.25.49 age.50.57 age.58.65 age.66.70
#1         x     y         0         0         0         0         0
#2         x     y         0         0         0         0         0
#3         x     y         0         0         0         0         0
#4         x     y         0         0         0         0         0
#5         x     y         0         0         0         0         0
```

However, usually `NA` values would be more appropriate than `0`.

Comment: Wow, this is really elegant.In general, I agree about the NA comment - in this specific case, 0 is what I'm looking for.